# How to write switch cases in a function in react using Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project in that I have a button, for that button I have written one function to change background color, but What I exactly need is when the device size is 320px then when I click the button its background color has to change to red. Again if device size is 768px then When I click the button its background color has to change to green. for this I am trying to use switch case but I don't know how to write switch case in a function
so please help me to achieve this

This is my code

This is App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [backGroundColor, setBackGroundColor] = useState(null)

  const [deviceSize, changeDeviceSize] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  const changeBackGroundColor = () => {
    console.log(deviceSize, '***')
    setBackGroundColor({
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    })
    switch (deviceSize === 320) {
      
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
  }, [])

  
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-12'>
          <div className='first'>
            <button onClick={changeBackGroundColor} style={backGroundColor} className='btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

If you have any questions please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use media query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want switch case, you can do like this:

```
switch (deviceSize) {
  case 320: 
    setBackGroundColor({
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    });
    break;
  case 768: 
    setBackGroundColor({
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    });
    break;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Viet I am very thankful for your answer, but In my code some problem is there initially when my device size is 320px at that time initial button background color is blue when I click it then it's background color is changing to red now when I go to 768px here also it showing background red only. can you please tell me how to fix this issue.

Comment: If you want to change color when you change the size of the window, you can use `addEventListener('resize', yourFunction);`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

The background will change automatically when screen size changed.

### App.js

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [btnClass, setBtnClass] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setBtnClass('btn btn-primary');
  }, []);

  const onClick = (e) => {
    setBtnClass('btn btn-active');
  }

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-12'>
          <div className='first'>
            <button
              onClick={onClick}
              className={btnClass}
            >Click here</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

### App.css

```css
.btn {
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .btn-active {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .btn-active {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
``
```